# Git LFS cannot find object for new repo

Tags: github, git-lfs

I'm trying to push some UE4 assets from a local brand new git project to a new github repo. I started with:

```
> git init
> git lfs track *.uasset
> git lfs track *.umap
> git add .git*
> git add path/to/asset.uasset
> git commit -m "init repo"
> git remote add origin git@github:my_repo.git
> git push -u origin master
```

Then I get:

```
Git LFS upload failed:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s
  (missing) Content/Assets/Landscape/M_Landscape_Master.uasset (9ec478c231daf870ad7ab6535c3beb403a63f68a305073506decd24ac66ad122)
hint: Your push was rejected due to missing or corrupt local objects.
hint: You can disable this check with: `git config lfs.allowincompletepush true`
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:my_repo.git'
```

`git lfs push --all origin master` gives the same error here.

`git lfs fetch --all` returns:

```
fetch: 1 object found, done.
fetch: Fetching all references...
[9ec478c231daf870ad7ab6535c3beb403a63f68a305073506decd24ac66ad122] Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server
error: failed to fetch some objects from 'https://github.com/my_repo.git/info/lfs'
```

My environment:

- Win10
- git: git version 2.36.1.windows.1
- lfs: git-lfs/3.1.4 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.17.8)

Comment: What do `git lfs ls-files` and `git lfs env` show? What about other items from [this tutorial](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial)?